# Spark: Remove null values after from_json or just get value from a json

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with a JSON data column:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
     [
         (1, '{"a": "hello"}'),
         (2, '{"b": ["foo", "bar"]}'),
         (3, '{"c": {"cc": "baz"}}'),
         (4, '{"d": [{"dd": "foo"}, {"dd": "bar"}]}'),
     ],
     schema=['id', 'jsonData'],
)

df.show()
+---+--------------------+
| id|            jsonData|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|      {"a": "hello"}|
|  2|{"b": ["foo", "ba...|
|  3|{"c": {"cc": "baz"}}|
|  4|{"d": [{"dd": "fo...|
+---+--------------------+
```

The key is the schema identifier. That is, two keys cannot have a different schema

I need to parse jsons in this column and get value from each dict.

I run next commands:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select("jsonData").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])).schema
df = df.withColumn("jsonParsedData", from_json("jsonData", json_schema))

df.show()
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|            jsonData|      jsonParsedData|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|      {"a": "hello"}|          [hello,,,]|
|  2|{"b": ["foo", "ba...|    [, [foo, bar],,]|
|  3|{"c": {"cc": "baz"}}|         [,, [baz],]|
|  4|{"d": [{"dd": "fo...|[,,, [[foo], [bar]]]|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I got a `jsonParsedData` column with `null` values for missing keys.

**Question**: how to parse JSON from a `jsonData` column and get a column without `null` values for missing keys.

I think that the `jsonParsedData` column should have a `string` type.

**Expected result**:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|            jsonData|      jsonParsedData|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|      {"a": "hello"}|               hello|
|  2|{"b": ["foo", "ba...|          [foo, bar]|
|  3|{"c": {"cc": "baz"}}|       {"cc": "baz"}|
|  4|{"d": [{"dd": "fo...|[{"dd": "foo"}, {...|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extracting the value from the json using `regexp_extract`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('jsonParsedData', F.regexp_extract('jsonData', '\\{"[^"]+": (.*)\\}', 1))

df2.show(truncate=False)
+---+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|id |jsonData                             |jsonParsedData                |
+---+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|1  |{"a": "hello"}                       |"hello"                       |
|2  |{"b": ["foo", "bar"]}                |["foo", "bar"]                |
|3  |{"c": {"cc": "baz"}}                 |{"cc": "baz"}                 |
|4  |{"d": [{"dd": "foo"}, {"dd": "bar"}]}|[{"dd": "foo"}, {"dd": "bar"}]|
+---+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Another perhaps better way is to use `from_json` with a schema of `map<string, string>`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('jsonParsedData', F.map_values(F.from_json('jsonData', 'map<string,string>'))[0])

df2.show(truncate=False)
+---+-------------------------------------+---------------------------+
|id |jsonData                             |jsonParsedData             |
+---+-------------------------------------+---------------------------+
|1  |{"a": "hello"}                       |hello                      |
|2  |{"b": ["foo", "bar"]}                |["foo","bar"]              |
|3  |{"c": {"cc": "baz"}}                 |{"cc":"baz"}               |
|4  |{"d": [{"dd": "foo"}, {"dd": "bar"}]}|[{"dd":"foo"},{"dd":"bar"}]|
+---+-------------------------------------+---------------------------+
```